# Reading a nested object parsed from a JSON string in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON string and it is not as straightforward as I would like. I am hoping for a bit of help. I need to iterate over each entry comparing it to another set of values that are also in a JSON string (which is structured much easier for me). I am looking for a suggested pattern getting the data out and using it in a compare and then if it's the result I want - print it.

The JSON:

```
{"success":true,
"message":"",
"result":
     {"buy":
            [
             {"Quantity":2.40078779,"Rate":1.11811290},  
             {"Quantity":0.00085042,"Rate":1.11584924} ....
```

And so on. There a a LOT of values. The way I am getting at the data is like this:

```
print ("Buy: ",b1['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'], ",",b1['result']['buy'][0]['Rate'])
```

It's the middle [0] this is getting me - I can imagine I could get the number of entries, then loop through i = 0 to range(number of entries) but it really throws my logic off as the other JSON strings with entries I am comparing are structured much easier:

example of the easy (for me) JSON entry:

```
{
    "eth_btc":{
        "asks":[
            [105,1],
            [105.5,15],
            [104.504,0.425],
            [105.505,0.1]
        ],
        "bids":[
            [109,6],
            [113.082,0.46540304],
            [104.91,0.99007913],
            [106.83,0.07832332]
        ]
    }
}


for asks in easyJson['eth_btc']['asks']:
    print (asks)
```

I need to compare this asks value which is easy to iterate over against the rate value in the above string. Since the structure is different (and I am learning Python as a hobby) I cannot wrap my head around the best way to iterate through these sets of data structured differently. The datasets will be LARGE, comparing 4000 or so values living in 5 sets of data against each other, ONE BY ONE, to find the just the right pair based on my criteria.

Should I normalize all of the data FROM JSON into something else, then do my comparisons there? This is a 5 way compare with thousands of values.

pseudo - code:

```
If ask1 < bid2 then if volume of ask1 is <= volume of bid2 then do something
   etc - then ask1 vs bid3, and so on..
       ask2 vs bid1, ask2 vs bid3 ...
          ask3 vs bid1, ask3 vs bid2, ask3 vs bid4 ...
```

Apologies if this isn't clear. I am trying to tackle this project head on and I feel like I am brute forcing it and not using the power of Python and I want to learn!!!!

Thanks for any help - direction - anything !

Comment: `import json; json.loads(json_string)` That will put it instantly into a `dict` / `list` structure. Also I think the way you are going about this is really bad (I'm a quant) if you are looking to do some kind of market microstructure analysis on JSON files that will be far too slow. By the time your python code evaluates the result will be useless

Comment: Secondly as a more SO question presentation issue - you have a really scatty question that sort of rambles and ends up going nowhere. Try and pin down your question to one thing at a time. For example 1) Are you wanting to parse JSON ? 2) Are you wanting to know how to compare values in a dictionary?  -- both these questions are heavily covered on SO. For these reasons I'm voting to close as it's too broad

Comment: Since you're already able to access data by index, what you have now is a `dict` or `list`. You don't need to covert it into anything else.

Comment: Are you asking how best to handle two different JSON file simultaneously that have different structures, or how to handle two different files with different structures from the same code? Or is there some other specific question you were asking?

Comment: I was hoping the description of what I am trying to do would put the original question into context. I understand putting the json into a dictionary, hence the code I provided. I just skipped typing the import and the loads lines. The point is the datasets I am trying to compare have a different structure and I am trying to determine the best way to compare them. I am not doing MICRO analysis, but MACRO, so timing in under a minute to cycle through all of the data from each exchange would be fine, and would also automatically not violate the number of api calls.

Comment: The JSON strings are examples of strings that come from two different web locations. In reality there are 5 different feeds I wish to compare (per the pseudo-code). I can brute force it - I know how to iterate with embedded loops and I understand I can use the zip function to zip the feeds that have the same format together if I want - but I have feeds with different structures and I am looking for a strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out the first part of the question - how to get at the data I was interested in:

```
import json
b="""{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"buy":[{"Quantity":6.67178734,"Rate":0.01390041},{"Quantity":244.11602480,"Rate":0.01386500},{"Quantity":34.17058305,"Rate":0.01385014},{"Quantity":48.76276808,"Rate":0.01383242},{"Quantity":2.00000000,"Rate":0.01383239},{"Quantity":0.07212509,"Rate":0.01383000},{"Quantity":256.05669876,"Rate":0.01381066},{"Quantity":75.00000000,"Rate":0.01381065},{"Quantity":0.12796429,"Rate":0.01381050},{"Quantity":11.51657190,"Rate":0.01381048},{"Quantity":0.07895698,"Rate":0.01381047},{"Quantity":1.00000000,"Rate":0.01380653},{"Quantity":1.07501432,"Rate":0.01380650},{"Quantity":22.18832778,"Rate":0.01380474}]}}
"""
b1 = json.loads(b)
buy = list(b1['result']['buy'])
for item in buy:
    print ("Rate: ",item['Rate'], "Quantity: ",item['Quantity'])
```

I needed to create a list for the data I needed - otherwise I could not figure out how to iterate through it cleanly. If there is a better way of doing this, please advise. I would rather not take DICT object and cast it into a list, but otherwise the way this data is formatted I couldn't figure out how to cleanly iterate through it.